# Laravel Submit button re-routing to Home Page

Tags: php, laravel

So I used the default Registration Form Laravel.

Made copy of the Registration Form to make a slightly different one.

Basically there is two sign up forms

1. Starter - original
2. Bronze - Copy

**--My Routing List--**

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/register', function(){
  return View::make('auth.register');
});

Route::get('/bronze', function(){
  return View::make('auth.bronze');
});

Route::get('/login', function(){
  return View::make('auth.login');
});
```

Now every time I submit the bronze sign up form, it redirects me to my home page.

I'm thinking maybe its my Action call in my view. which is identical to the Starter Form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/register') }}">
```

if I'm correct what I just did is bad practice, but I'm a new-bie at this framework.

Comment: The one thing I pick up on is that your form is POSTing the data, whilst your routes are all GET routes. I would spend far more time reading through the Laravel documentation and watching Laracasts to gain a better understanding of the framework before proceeding.

Comment: You right Thomas...I will have to make time for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly add a POST route, as the `Auth::routes()` method only handles calls to `/register`:

`Route::post('/bronze', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');`

And make sure you submit the Bronze form to the same route:

`<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="/bronze">`

Alternatively, and possibly a better solution, would be to just use the same registration form and have an input for their account type selection:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="/register">

    <input type="radio" name="type" id="type-starter" value="starter">
    <label for="type-starter">Starter</label>

    <input type="radio" name="type" id="type-bronze" value="bronze">
    <label for="type-bronze">Bronze</label>
```

Comment: I did it like you said but still...it keeps redirecting home...this time it wont even go to the Form when you click the link...

Comment: and the method doesnt exist...there is only validator() and create() in my RegisterController

Answer (score 0):

Old question but had a similar issue.

Don't forget to include `csrf` token in all your forms if you have that middleware enabled.

These days it's as simple as calling a blade helper:

```
<form action="..." method="...">
    @csrf
    ...
</form>
```